# nodejs middleware delaying requests

Tags: node.js, middleware

I'm writing a middleware which will perform a sequence of actions. After the sequence is done, I want the middleware to call next(). from this point on the middleware is redundant.
I've written the following code: (here the sequence of actions is mocked by a call to setTimeout):

```
function myMiddleware(req, res, next){

   console.info("inside myMiddleware");

   if (actionDone) {
       console.info("middleware redundant. ActionDone, calling next");
       next();
   }

   setTimeout(doneWaiting, 30000);

   function doneWaiting(){
      actionDone = true;
      next();
   }
}
```

This code will not work because if more than one request arrives before the action is done, setTimeout will be called again and again. I want setTimeout to be called only once, and only when it's done I want to call next() on all the requests which arrived so far.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to perform a task and handle all requests once the task is finished? Until that happens they wait?

So here's non scalable way:

```
var EventManager = new require("events").EventEmitter( );
var actionDone = "start";

function myMiddleware(req, res, next){

   console.info("inside myMiddleware");
   var handler = function( ) {
       console.info("middleware redundant. ActionDone, calling next");
       next();
   };

   if (actionDone === "finished" ) {
       handler( );
       return;
   }

   EventManager.once( "finished", handler );

   if (actionDone !== "working") {
       actionDone = "working";
       function doneWaiting(){
          actionDone = "finished";
          EventManager.trigger( "finished" );
       }
       setTimeout(doneWaiting, 30000);
   }
}
```

Obviously it is not scalable, because you cannot share `EventManager` object between machines. In order to do that between machines you would probably have to fire requests from the main server to every other server and handle the request similarly.

**WARNING:** what you trying to do looks like a very very bad idea. After all requests should not depend on each other. This can easily lead to server crash.

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is a bad idea, but what do you suggest I should do if I have to make sure some action is done before handling my requests? suppose all my requests depend on a creation of a table which may take time to create, is there a better approach in this case?

Comment: @user429400 I suggest putting a self referencing function which will periodically ( for example once per second ) check whether the table is ready or not ( you need to flag it that it is ready of course ). After for example 5 tries you should break the loop and respond with `sorry, table not ready - try again later` ( this is only to make sure that request does not loop infinetly ) . That's how I would do that. Also it is scalable out of the box ( assuming you use database for storing the table ).

Answer (score 0):

Set `actionDone` variable to `req`, this way

```
function myMiddleware(req, res, next){

console.info("inside myMiddleware");

if (req.actionDone) {
    console.info("middleware redundant. ActionDone, calling next");
    next();
}

setTimeout(doneWaiting, 30000);

function doneWaiting(){
   req.actionDone = true;
   next();
}
```

}